# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telerik.plugins

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, telerik, classnotfoundexception

I am trying develop a ionic application. I built it successfully, but when I open the application, it closes.
The error from `logcat` is:

```
$ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions.NativePageTransitions.
```

I think that it is about camera plugin, because in `package.json` I have.

```
"cordovaPlugins": [
{
  "locator": "https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin",
  "id": "cordova-plugin-x-toast"
},
"cordova-plugin-camera",
{
  "locator": "https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions#0.5.5",
  "id": "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions"
},
{
  "locator": "https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications",
  "id": "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification"
},
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer",
"cordova-plugin-file"
```

],

But I don't know how fix up.
Please I need help.
Thanks for any response.

Comment: You should also include the logs for the community to help you more.

Comment: And some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was because I downloaded the project from github, and it had added the android platform and the camera plugin.
I remove node_modules, android platform and camera plugin directories. I redo the commands "$ npm install", "$ bower install" and "$ ionic platform add android" and the application execute fine.